# Append DOM objects to qunit-fixture + Qunit

Tags: javascript, qunit

I am working on  javaScript unit-testing by Qunit framework. I have DOM object with a Form and Textbox in it.

```
 <div>
  <form action="/" id="Form1" method="post">
  <div>
    <input  data-val="true" data-val-fileextensions="The DocumentFileName field only 
            accepts files with the following extensions: doc,docx,txt,rtf,pdf" data-
            val-fileextensions-fileextensions="doc,docx,txt,rtf,pdf" id="Text1" 
            name="FileExtensiondTest.fileExtensionInValid.DocumentFileName" type="text" 
            value="test.ppt" />
  </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

I would to add above DOM object to qunit-fixture and access DOM object attributes in Test cases  such as  below:

```
    ok($("#FileExtensiondTest_fileExtensionInValid_DocumentFileName").hasClass("input-
         validation-error"), "True, Valid Test");
```

I tried adding DOM to qunit-fixture by below line of code:

```
    $("#qunit-fixture").append('<div><form action="/" id="Form1" method="post"><div>        
      <input  data-val="true" data-val-fileextensions="The DocumentFileName field 
        only accepts files with the following extensions: doc,docx,txt,rtf,pdf" data-
        val-fileextensions-fileextensions="doc,docx,txt,rtf,pdf" id="Text1" 
        name="FileExtensiondTest.fileExtensionInValid.DocumentFileName" type="text" 
        value="test.ppt" /></div></form></div>');
```

Am I doing in the right way..Need your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

In Your code :

```
ok(
  $("#FileExtensiondTest_fileExtensionInValid_DocumentFileName")
    .hasClass("input-validation-error"), 
  true, 
  "Valid Test"
);
```

Did you try changing **"#FileExtensiondTest_fileExtensionInValid_DocumentFileName"** with "**#FileExtensiondTest.fileExtensionInValid.DocumentFileName**" or "**#Text1**"

Let know what was the solution. Once you solve it. Good Luck!